# Jersey как составить запрос на авторизацию?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

В общем написал GET запрос, на получение данных c кнопки отвечающий за реиндекс. Но почему то  GET запрос требует авторизации а я не знаю что ему предложить \;_;/.

П.с. Выкладываю весь код

```
package reindex1;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class Program {

    private static Scanner in;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите адрес страницы для реиндекса: ");
        String str = in.nextLine();
        if(str.isEmpty())
            str = "http://n7701-sys253:8080/plugins/servlet/restbrowser#/resource/api-2-projectcategory";

        System.out.println(str);

        try {
            Client client = Client.create();

            WebResource webResource = client.resource(str);
            String str1 = "curl \\\""+str+"\\\"";

            NewCookie cookie = new NewCookie("kononov", "P@ssw0rd");

            ClientResponse response = webResource.accept( str1 
                    + "-X GET"
                    + cookie
                    + "-H \"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch\" "
                    + "-H \"Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4\" "
                    + "-H \"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36\" "
                    + "-H \"Content-Type: application/json\" "
                    + "-H \"Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01\" "
                    + "-H \"Referer: http://n7701-sys253:8080/plugins/servlet/restbrowser\" "
                    + "-H \"X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\" "
                    + "-H \"Connection: keep-alive\" "
                    + "--compressed")
                    .get(ClientResponse.class);

            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + response.getStatus());
            }

            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            System.out.println(output);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот что я на выходе (в консоли получил). Весь вывод я не могу выложить из за предела количества знаков в сообщении. Но последние три абзаца я выложил.

```
 ....................
<section class="footer-body">
<ul class="atlassian-footer">
    <li>
        Atlassian JIRA <a class="seo-link" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira">Project Management Software</a>
                                            <span id="footer-build-information">(v7.7.1#77002-<span title='e75ca93d5574d9409c0630b81c894d9065296414' data-commit-id='e75ca93d5574d9409c0630b81c894d9065296414}'>sha1:e75ca93</span>)</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="about-link" rel="nofollow" href="/secure/AboutPage.jspa/secure/AboutPage.jspa">About JIRA</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="footer-report-problem-link" rel="nofollow" href="/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa">Report a problem</a>
    </li>
</ul>
    <ul class="atlassian-footer">
        <li class="licensemessage">

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="footer-logo"><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.atlassian.com/">Atlassian</a></div>
</section>
<fieldset class="hidden parameters">
    <input type="hidden" title="loggedInUser" value="">
    <input type="hidden" title="ajaxTimeout" value="Вызов сервера JIRA не был завершен в течение тайм-аута.  Мы не уверены в результате этой операции.">
    <input type="hidden" title="JiraVersion" value="7.7.1" />
    <input type="hidden" title="ajaxUnauthorised" value="Вы не авторизованы для выполнения этой операции. Пожалуйста, войдите.">
    <input type="hidden" title="baseURL" value="http://n7701-sys253:8080" />
    <input type="hidden" title="ajaxCommsError" value="Невозможно связаться с сервером JIRA. Это может быть временный сбой или сервер недоступен. ">
    <input type="hidden" title="ajaxServerError" value="Сервер JIRA доступен, но вернул сообщение об ошибке. Мы не уверены в результате этой операции.">
    <input type="hidden" title="ajaxErrorCloseDialog" value="Закройте это диалоговое окно и нажмите обновление в браузере">
    <input type="hidden" title="ajaxErrorDialogHeading" value="Разрыв связи">

    <input type="hidden" title="dirtyMessage" value="Вы ввели новую информацию на этой странице. Если вы покинете страницу, предварительно не сохранив изменения, они будут потеряны.">
    <input type="hidden" title="dirtyDialogMessage" value="Вы ввели в это окно новые данные. Если вы уйдете из этого окна, не сохранив данные, все изменения будут потеряны. Чтобы вернуться к окну, нажмите «отменить».">
    <input type="hidden" title="keyType" value="Тип">
    <input type="hidden" title="keyThen" value="затем">
    <input type="hidden" title="dblClickToExpand" value="Двойное нажатие для раскрытия">
    <input type="hidden" title="actions" value="Действия">
    <input type="hidden" title="removeItem" value="Удалить">
    <input type="hidden" title="workflow" value="Бизнес-процесс">
    <input type="hidden" title="labelNew" value="Новая метка">
    <input type="hidden" title="issueActionsHint" value="Начните набирать для поиска доступных операций или нажмите вниз, чтобы увидеть все">
    <input type="hidden" title="closelink" value="Закрыть">
    <input type="hidden" title="dotOperations" value="Действия">
    <input type="hidden" title="dotLoading" value="Загрузка...">
    <input type="hidden" title="frotherSuggestions" value="Предложения">
    <input type="hidden" title="frotherNomatches" value="Нет совпадений">
    <input type="hidden" title="multiselectVersionsError" value="{0} не является корректной версией.">
    <input type="hidden" title="multiselectComponentsError" value="{0} - некорректный компонент.">
    <input type="hidden" title="multiselectGenericError" value="Некорректное значение {0}.">
</fieldset>

            </footer>

    </div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/s/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e-CDN/fba21d/77002/be09033ea7858348cd8d5cdeb793189a/1.0/_/download/batch/jira.webresources:bigpipe-js/jira.webresources:bigpipe-js.js" data-wrm-key="jira.webresources:bigpipe-js" data-wrm-batch-type="resource" data-initially-rendered></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/s/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e-CDN/fba21d/77002/be09033ea7858348cd8d5cdeb793189a/1.0/_/download/batch/jira.webresources:bigpipe-init/jira.webresources:bigpipe-init.js" data-wrm-key="jira.webresources:bigpipe-init" data-wrm-batch-type="resource" data-initially-rendered></script>

<form id="jira_request_timing_info" class="dont-default-focus" >
    <fieldset class="parameters hidden">
        <input type="hidden" title="jira.request.start.millis" value="1519133898917" />
        <input type="hidden" title="jira.request.server.time" value="62" />
        <input type="hidden" title="jira.request.id" value="998x2648x1" />
        <input type="hidden" title="jira.session.expiry.time" value="-" />
        <input type="hidden" title="jira.session.expiry.in.mins" value="-" />
        <input id="jiraConcurrentRequests" type="hidden" name="jira.request.concurrent.requests" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" title="db.conns.time.in.ms" value="2" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
<!--
                     REQUEST ID : 998x2648x1
              REQUEST TIMESTAMP : [20/Feb/2018:16:38:18 +0300]
                   REQUEST TIME : 0,0620
                     ASESSIONID : -
            CONCURRENT REQUESTS : 1

                          db.conns : OpSnapshot{name='db.conns', invocationCount=4, elapsedTotal=2181043, elapsedMin=275617, elapsedMax=906635, resultSetSize=0, cpuTotal=0, cpuMin=0, cpuMax=0}
-->
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: судя по импортам, используете древнюю версию JAX-RS апи. Есть ли на то весомая причина? Почему в webResource.accept() у вас запихано столько всего разного, когда там должен быть указан только MIME-type (напр., "text/plain")?.

Comment: @fromSPb Это рест запрос на нажатие кнопки, скопирован из инструментария разработчика (Хром), после нажатия кнопки я получил в вкладке Network запрос, после чего его скопировал (Copy as cURL(cmd)) и вставил в строку  ClientResponse response = webResource.accept(.....).get(ClientResponse.class);